# Wrapping Content Elements via Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid-layout, fluid

I am experimenting with TYPO3 and Fluid and at the moment I am in trouble. It is about a `backendlayout` I created in TYPO3.

> It consists of two content areas: "**left-column**" and
>   "**right-column**".

To bring them to frontend appearance via fluid was no problem. But then I created four content elements (text and image ) within "left column". I wanted to wrap each of these content elements with a bootstrap wrapper e.g. text `"col-md-8"` and `img "col-md-4"`.

Unfortunately, I have not found any hints or documentation how to do this. Maybe someone can help me with that issue and tell me how to customize the wrappers of my content elements. Is it possible to do it via Fluid at all?

Answer (score 5):

Backend layouts are used to map columns to your template, but they doesn't allow you to decide how each of them will be displayed. There are several solutions... but last time my favorite is extension [**Grid Elements**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/).

It allows you to create sub-containers for Content Elements, so you can add, any combination of Bootstrap's grid layout (i.e. `2 columns - 4-8` or `3 columns - 3-3-3` etc...) and then wrap it whit Bootstrap classes.

Sample for mentioned  `2 columns - 4-8` Grid Element record:

**Title:** `2 columns: 4-8` or whatever you want ;)

**Alias:** `2_columns_4_8` (must be unique)

**Grid Configuration:**

```
backend_layout {
    colCount = 2
    rowCount = 1
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = Left
                    colPos = 221
                }
                2 {
                    name = Right
                    colPos = 222
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally in your TypoScript template** add rendering definition like this:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    2_columns_4_8 < .default
    2_columns_4_8 {
        wrap = <div class="row">|</div>
        columns {
            221 < .default
            221.wrap = <div class="col-sm-4">|</div>

            222 < .default
            222.wrap = <div class="col-sm-8">|</div>
        }
    }
}
```

(*in the sample observe where and how **alias** and also **colPos** values are used later in TypoScript*)

**hint:** Don't waste time for creating any possible combination of columns at beginning, instead create one *ad hoc* when required, usually you need only few of them.

**P.S.** TYPO3 is written uppercase, always!